# Download manager which would have file indexing and allow descriptions

Tags: windows, file-management, download-manager

I am regularly downloading various files (htm, pdf, doc) from the internet through my browser for learning and education purposes and save them in my downloads folder.

Over time I cannot remember what file is about what topic so I am looking for a software (standalone Windows or Firefox compatible) that would act like a download manager in a way that I would be able to see a date-specific index of files and have the capacity for me to add a description for each download so that when I want to find something after a year I can get to it quickly.

Alternatively, the software could be a file manager that would scan actively scan a designated folder (such as the download folder) and when a new file is saved it would prompt me to add it to the index and add a description.

Answer (score 1):

Some download managers like [FlashGet](http://www.flashget.com/) has the ability to use categories when downloading files. For example, you make a 'PDF' category and its location: `...\download\pdf`. Then, in the download prompt of a pdf file, you select this category and it automatically downloads it to that folder.

Also, categories are shown in the sidebar and you can see all the downloaded files in that categories with their details like downloaded date, ...

Comment: Thank you. I think what would be good is a file tracker. In the sense that you open the programme and it would show a list of files and then let me add a description to each file (within the programme) and later let me search the free text descriptions within the programme. So when my free text search finds a match from the description I created earlier, it would show me a link to the relevent file